# How to show volume names/labels in nautilus' "Other Locations" view?

Tags: nautilus

I've a USB disk that's set up as a VG called 'external' and has a series of LVs on it:

```
root@nuc:/home/avi# lvs external
  LV             VG       Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  home           external -wi-a-----  50.00g                                                    
  images         external -wi-a-----  30.00g                                                    
  laptop-backup  external -wi-ao---- 443.00g                                                    
  laptop-backup2 external -wi-a----- 325.00g                                                    
  pointtwo       external -wi-ao---- 600.00g                                                    
  root           external -wi-a-----  15.00g                                                    
  stuff          external -wi-ao---- 400.00g                                                    
root@nuc:/home/avi#
```

When I look at it in Nautilus all it shows me is the size of each:

[Nautilus other-locations view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJRlm.png)

What can or should I do to these devices (or nautilus) to get it to show me them with names rather than just capacities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each logical volume contains a file-system. If the file-system has a label, Nautilus will display the file-system-label instead of the file-system-size. So you need to give your file-systems labels (names). The commands to do that depend on the file-system-type.

Gather information about the filesystems with

```
lsblk -f
```

This will give you the device names and the used file-system-type

Here the commands for the most used file-sytem-types:

For ext2/3/4 use

```
sudo e2label /dev/??? YOURLABEL
or
sudo tune2fs -L YOURLABEL /dev/???
```

For NTFS use

```
sudo ntfslabel /dev/??? YOURLABEL
```

For FAT use

```
sudo fatlabel /dev/??? YOURLABEL
```